# Building OpenSSL to compile portable version of Python

Tags: python, linux, openssl

I am trying to build Python from source and need to include the SSL module for my web scraper to work with it.

I ran into the problem of SSL not being found, so I downloaded and built OpenSSL from source. The problem is, I need to install the development libraries along with OpenSSL in order for Python to run the `-lssl` parameter correctly when running `make`. I can't seem to find any documentation on how to build OpenSSL with the development libs, even though I'm sure it's got to be something simple I'm just missing.

I must do this from source; with no package managers. I have my reasons.

**EDIT:**
I have changed a few of the python configuration settings to try and fix the problem, and this is the compile error I am getting now:

`gcc -pthread  -Xlinker -export-dynamic -o python \
                Modules/python.o \
                libpython2.7.a -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -L/home/[username]/openssl-src -lssl -lcrypto   -lm

libpython2.7.a(posixmodule.o)(.text+0x4016): In function posix_tmpnam':<br />
./Modules/posixmodule.c:7346: warning: the use oftmpnam_r' is dangerous, better use mkstemp'
libpython2.7.a(posixmodule.o)(.text+0x3f76): In functionposix_tempnam':
./Modules/posixmodule.c:7301: warning: the use of tempnam' is dangerous, better usemkstemp'

./python: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

make: * [sharedmods] Error 127`

The "no such file or directory" is being thrown looking for a file that does exist in the `/home/[username]/openssl-src` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer doesn't EXACTLY answer my question, but I did find out what I needed to know so I will post it here. I had to change the location of the SSL files it was looking for to just `/usr` rather than `/usr/local`. RedHat by default has all the shared libraries in `/usr/lib` rather than `/usr/local/lib`, which is where it was looking by default.

Answer (score 1):

The default OpenSSL build should install the appropriate header files and libraries using `make install`, just make sure to provide the right prefix to the configure script (e.g., `./configure --prefix=/usr`).

If this fails, please post the exact error that gcc shows.

By the way, please consider using an automated tool such as [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) for building Python. I think the standard recipes take care of SSL support (possibly even downloading and compiling OpenSSL), although I am not certain about this.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand the use of `make` versus `make install`. I thought that all `make install` did was build it in a different location (such as the /usr/bin that you specified). In any case, I will post the compile error I am getting now in the original message. I cannot click on the link you posted due to network restrictions at my workplace. :(

Comment: Looks like you do not have the permission to install the libraries in a system location, so you will have to provide the path to OpenSSL when configuring Python. I don't remember exactly, but I think setting the environment variable CFLAGS to "-L/home/user/openssl-src/lib" (or whatever directory of the library) before running Python's `configure` script could help.

Answer (score 1):

in the Bourne shell (/bin/sh or /bin/bash):

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ make
```

in the C-shell (/bin/csh or /bin/tcsh):

```
% setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib
% make
```

Comment: change "/usr/local/lib" to your path of openssl lib